# Override of getDropDownView in ArrayAdapter in order to change color of particular row in dropdown also change color of another rows

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I want to change color of the first item in the spinner dropdown.
One of the solutions is to override getDropDownView method:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sprache_ratoromanisch_adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                    getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    list_sprache_ratoromanisch) {

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    View row = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if(position == 0) {
                       row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    }
                    return(row);
                }
            };
```

But I have a problem - if the number of elements is big enough and they are  exceeding visible part of the spinner - first and second elements that are invisible before scrolling also change color when they become visible.
[items in spinner's dropdown change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqcnU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Here is the correct version.

```
final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> sprache_ratoromanisch_adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
                    getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    list_sprache_ratoromanisch) {

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                    View row = null;

                    if(position == 0) {
                        row = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                     }
                    else {
                        row = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
                    }
                    return row;
                }
            };
```

Comment: The reason is that convertView is a "recycled view". When the first item goes out of the screen, its view is sent back for the item entering the screen to save more rendering computation. Hence the repetition of background color.